# adding directory present in mac os .app into PYTHONPATH in Spyder

Tags: python, macos, python-module, pythonpath, spyder

I have a directory */Applications/Trelis-15.0.app/Contents/MacOS* that has python scripts that I want to use in Spyder. Unfortunately I cannot add this directory using the *Pythonpath Manager* because it doesn't allow to set the path containing a ".app".
How can I do to import the scripts present into that directory?

Thanks

Comment: Is creating a soft link to that directory an option?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it has to be a path